Can $f\circ f$ be defined when $f:\emptyset \to \mathbb{R}$?
Along the lines of this post
Let $f:\emptyset \to \mathbb{R}$
How can we define the composition of $f$ with itself?
In any other case $f\circ f$ would be defined in a set $B=\{ x\in A  \land  f(x)\in A\}$ where A is the domain of $f$. But since here $f$ is defined in the empty set , so the statements $x\in A$ and $f(x)\in A$ make no sense since there is no $x$ .
What I have thought is
$$(f\circ f)(x)=f(f(x)),\forall x\in\emptyset$$
If we are considering functions as sets of ordered pairs, the empty function is represented as the empty set of pairs: $$f=\emptyset$$ and so the composition $f\circ f $ would also be the empty set because there are no pairs to compose. $$f\circ f=\emptyset$$
From the post linked above and my experience. For a function $f:\emptyset \to Y$ the composition $f\circ f$ is again an empty function $\emptyset\to Y$. This aligns with the formal properties of function composition where the domain remains empty and thus the result is trivially an empty function.

Do your functions have co-domain as part of the function? Is so, then not for that particular empty function $f:\emptyset\to\mathbb{R}$ that you wrote. To compose a function with itself you need a function from a set to the same set. You can compose the empty function $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset$.
If your functions don't have codomain (are only the set of pair in the relation), then sure $f=\emptyset$ and $f\circ f={(x,y)\in\emptyset^2\mid \exists z\in\emptyset, (x,z)\in f\text{ and }(z,y)\in f}=\emptyset$

What you can do instead is to revert to the formal set theoretic definition of a function as a set of ordered pairs (satisfying some properties). You can then apply the definition of function composition expressed using that formal definition, with the result that
$$f \circ f = \{(x,z) \,\,\mid \,\, \exists y \,\,\text{such that}\,\, (x,y) \in f \,\,\text{and}\,\, (y,z) \in f\}
$$
This set is the empty set: since $f$ itself is the empty set, the statement $(x,y) \in f$ is false no matter what $x$ and $y$ are.
By the way, the statement $x \in A$ certainly makes sense, it's just that this statement is false for all $x$: the domain of $f$ is $A=\emptyset$ and $x \in \emptyset$ is false for all $x$. The statement $f(x) \in A$ is more problematical, because as you say $f(x)$ its undefined no matter what $x$ is. This is one of the reasons that the more formal approach is useful, where $f$ is treated as a set of ordered pairs.

I think that this has nothing to do with the empty set and that your question can be generalised as:

Let $f: A \to B$ with $A,B$ as subsets of the same ambient space $C$ where the image of $f$, $f(A)$, is a subset of (not only $B$ but also) $A$. How do you define some kind of self-composition '$f \circ f$' from $A$ to $B$ when $B$ isn't a subset of $A$?

Answer:

Restrict the range of $f$ to its image to obtain $\tilde f:A \to f(A)$, $\tilde f(x) := f(x)$ (s.t. of course $\tilde f(A) = f(A)$.

Use the inclusion map $i: f(A) \to A$, $i(x) := x$

Then the self-composition '$f \circ f$' is $f \circ i \circ \tilde f: A \to f(A) \to A \to B$, $f \circ i \circ \tilde f(x) := (f \circ i \circ \tilde f)(x) = f(i(\tilde f(x)) = f(i(f(x)) = f(f(x))$


Example:
Consider the half-parabola $f: [0,\infty) \to [0.5,\infty), f(x)=x^2+1$.
Here, $A = [0,\infty)$, $f(A) = [1,\infty)$, $B = [0.5,\infty)$ and $C = \mathbb R$.
Indeed the image of $f$ is $[1,\infty)$, so while we can't exactly define '$f \circ f$' since $[0.5,\infty)$ isn't a subset of $[1,\infty)$, we can define $f \circ i \circ \tilde f$ as follows.

Restrict the range of $f$ to its image to obtain  $\tilde f:A = [0,\infty) \to f(A) = [1,\infty)$, $\tilde f(x) := f(x) = x^2$

Use the inclusion map $i: f(A) = [1,\infty) \to A = [0,\infty)$, $i(x) := x$

Then the self-composition '$f \circ f$' is  $f \circ i \circ \tilde f: A = [0,\infty) \to f(A) = [1,\infty) \to A = [0,\infty) \to B = [0.5,\infty)$, $(f \circ i \circ \tilde f)(x) = f(i(\tilde f(x)) = f(i(f(x)) = f(f(x)) = (x^2+1)^2+1 = x^4+2x^2+2$


In your case
$A = \emptyset$, $f(A) = \emptyset$, $B = \mathbb R = C$.
